# How to pass a reference of scope's model to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to pass a reference of scope's model to a function, where I can edit the contents of it?

For example, I have controller like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.magic = 123;

    $scope.someMethod = function(model) {
        model = 321;
    }
});
```

And a view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    ...

    <input type="text" data-ng-model="magic">

    <button type="button" data-ng-click="someMethod(magic)">
</div>
```

Now when I click the button, it almost works, but after `someMethod`, the actual $scope.magic has not changed, it's still 321. So apparently `someMethod` creates a copy of the model, not reference. How to get the reference instead?

Comment: The problem is that you're passing a primitive to the function and then merely overwrite the variable. This is not going to reflect on the outside world at all. Try making `magic` an object and modifying one of its properties...

Comment: You're passing a primitive in, so it's pass by value. Pass in an object to get pass by reference. But in either case, why not just update `$scope.magic` in `someMethod`?

Comment: _Always_ have a `.` in your models: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

Comment: deceze, thanks. That was the thing. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `someMethod` to the following:

```
$scope.someMethod = function(model) {
    model.magic = 321;
}

// Or accepting a new value
$scope.anotherMethod = function(model, value) {
    model.magic = value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="model.magic">
<button type="button" data-ng-click="someMethod(model)">Do Some Magic!</button>

<!-- Or with passing a new value -->
<button type="button" data-ng-click="anotherMethod(model, '123')">Do Some Magic!</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39ak4bvm/1/)

Comment: But then I'm bound to use only magic-property. I need it to be what ever variable what's passed in the function.